# Custom Text in WooCommerce Order Processing Email Based on Products

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to have some text added to the bottom of the Order Processing email that's sent to the customer when an order is placed if they purchase a product in the category of "Registration". BUT I DO NOT want the text to show if a product from another category was bought as well. I am able to display the desired text when a product in the "Registration" category is purchased successfully with the following code:

```
$order_id = $order->get_id();
$order      = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$items      = $order->get_items();

foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item_data ) {
    $product    = $item_data->get_product();
    $categories = array();

    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) ) {
            continue;
    }

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if(strtolower($term->name) === 'registration'){
            // Run any html code after this closing php tag -> ?>
            <p>
                Didn't get your gear yet? Click <a href="https://flexfootball.com/shop/">HERE</a> to order yours!
            </p>
        <?php } // Close "product is a registration form" condition
    }
}
```

And the text DOES NOT display if a product from another category is purchased. This is good, but if someone purchases a product from the "Registration" category AND another category, the code displays.

So to reiterate:
If an item is bought in the category "Registration", text IS displayed.
If an item is bought in a category OTHER than "Registration" text is NOT displayed.
If an item is bought in the category "Registration" AND another category, text is NOT displayed

I am thinking I need an `if` statement that is strict in that it is only true if "Registration" is the only category in the array.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```php
<?php
$order_id = $order->get_id();
$order    = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$items    = $order->get_items();
$is_valid = null;

foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item_data ) {
    $product    = $item_data->get_product();
    $categories = array();

    $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( is_wp_error( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if( false !== $is_valid && strtolower($term->name) === 'registration'){
            $is_valid = true;
            continue;
        }

        $is_valid = false;
    }
}

if ( $is_valid ) {
    // Run any html code after this closing php tag -> ?>
    <p>
        Didn't get your gear yet? Click <a href="https://flexfootball.com/shop/">HERE</a> to order yours!
    </p>
<?php // Close "product is a registration form" condition
}
```

The basic gist is that you are setting up `$is_valid` as a `NULL` value. If any category is *not* `registration`, then `$is_valid` becomes boolean `false`. If the category is `registration` AND `$is_valid` is not strictly (`!==`) `false`, set `$is_valid` to boolean `true`.

Finally, after the loops are done, if `$is_valid` is `true`, add the message.

Comment: Perfect! This did exactly what I needed. Thanks a million!

Comment: No problem, happy coding!